# Can we allow the user to insert a drop-down option in addition to the already present drop-down in a react application?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

While building a react application I want to enable a feature in the application to allow the user to add a new value in the drop-down. Is it possible to add this feature in the application?
Adding the following example

```
import React from "react";
import { MDBDropdown, MDBDropdownToggle, MDBDropdownMenu, MDBDropdownItem } from "mdbreact";

const DropdownPage = () => {
  return (
    <MDBDropdown>
      <MDBDropdownToggle caret color="primary">
        MDBDropdown
      </MDBDropdownToggle>
      <MDBDropdownMenu basic>
        <MDBDropdownItem>Action</MDBDropdownItem>
        <MDBDropdownItem>Another Action</MDBDropdownItem>
        <MDBDropdownItem>Something else here</MDBDropdownItem>
        <MDBDropdownItem divider />
        <MDBDropdownItem>Separated link</MDBDropdownItem>
      </MDBDropdownMenu>
    </MDBDropdown>
  );
}

export default DropdownPage;
```

After the divider can we add a '+' symbol and if the user clicks on it then he can type in a new value and that gets added to the existing dropdown. Can anyone please help with the following.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDBDropdown, MDBDropdownToggle, MDBDropdownMenu, MDBDropdownItem } from "mdbreact";

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDrop: false,
      isNewItem: false,
      items: ['Action', 'Another Action', 'Something else here'],
      newItem: ''
    }
  }
  render (){
    return (
      <MDBDropdown>
        <MDBDropdownToggle caret color="primary">
          MDBDropdown
        </MDBDropdownToggle>
        <MDBDropdownMenu>
          {
            this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
              return(
                <MDBDropdownItem key={index}>{item}</MDBDropdownItem>
              )
            })
          }
          <MDBDropdownItem divider />
          <MDBDropdownItem>Separated link</MDBDropdownItem>
          <MDBDropdownItem toggle={false} onClick={this.updateIsNewItem}>{this.state.isNewItem ? 'x' : '+'}</MDBDropdownItem>
          {
            this.state.isNewItem &&
            <MDBDropdownItem toggle={false}>
              <input name='newItem' type='text' onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.newItem}/>
              <button onClick={this.addNewItem}>Add</button>
            </MDBDropdownItem>
          }
        </MDBDropdownMenu>
      </MDBDropdown>

    )
  }

  addNewItem = () => {
    if(this.state.newItem !== ''){
      this.setState({
        items: [...this.state.items, this.state.newItem],
        newItem: '',
        isNewItem: false
      });
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;

    this.setState({[name]: value});
  }

  updateIsNewItem = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({isNewItem: !prevState.isNewItem}));
  }
}
```

Comment: In order to don't close the drop-down menu when you click on the item don't forget to put the toggle attribute to false: <MDBDropdownItem toggle = {false}/>